# Python partial function overload

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, overloading

Looking at the code below, is there a elegant way for the `Child` class to overload the `awesome_method()` method adding the `awesome_variable -= 5` statement *without* rewriting the `awesome_variable += 1` and `awesome_variable *= 2` statements in the overloaded method?

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, awesome_attribute):

        self.awesome_attribute = awesome_attribute

    def awesome_method(self):

        awesome_variable = self.awesome_attribute

        awesome_variable += 1

        awesome_variable *= 2

        return awesome_variable


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, awesome_attribute):
        super().__init__(awesome_attribute)

    def awesome_method(self):

        awesome_variable = self.awesome_attribute

        awesome_variable += 1

        awesome_variable -= 5

        awesome_variable *= 2

        return awesome_variable
```

Comment: You can simply call `super().awesome_method()` and continue with that returned value.

Comment: But in that case, I wouldn't be able to refactor `awesome_variable *= 2`?

Comment: No. It isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Dynamically modify specific operations within an existing method? No, that is not possible AFAIK. If you _know_ what the operations are, then you can just reverse them (`/=2`).

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way I can imagine without changing a lot the code:

```py
class Operation(object):
    def __init__(self, operation_type, value):
         
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, awesome_attribute):
        self.awesome_attribute = awesome_attribute

    def _awesome_method_middle_operations(self, awesome_variable):
        return awesome_variable

    def awesome_method(self):
        awesome_variable = self.awesome_attribute

        awesome_variable += 1
        awesome_variable = self._awesome_method_middle_operations(awesome_variable)
        awesome_variable *= 2

        return awesome_variable


class Child(Parent):
    def _awesome_method_middle_operations(self, awesome_variable):
        return awesome_variable - 5
```

A better approach changing your classes (you can adapt it to your own requirements):

```py
from typing import List


# This class encapsulates the operation itself.
class AwesomeOperation(object):
    OPERATION_TYPE_SUM = 0
    OPERATION_TYPE_MULT = 1
    OPERATION_TYPE_DIV = 2

    OPERATION_TYPES = (OPERATION_TYPE_SUM, OPERATION_TYPE_MULT, OPERATION_TYPE_DIV)

    def __init__(self, operation_type: OPERATION_TYPES, operation_value: float) -> None:
        self.operation_type = operation_type
        self.operation_value = operation_value

    def execute(self, value) -> float:
        if self.operation_type == self.OPERATION_TYPE_SUM:
            return value + self.operation_value
        elif self.operation_type == self.OPERATION_TYPE_MULT:
            return value * self.operation_value
        elif self.operation_type == self.OPERATION_TYPE_DIV:
            return value / self.operation_value
        else:
            return value


class AwesomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, awesome_attribute: float, awesome_operations: List[AwesomeOperation]):
        self.awesome_attribute = awesome_attribute
        self.awesome_operations = awesome_operations

    def awesome_method(self):
        awesome_variable = self.awesome_attribute

        # Now the method has not the operations directly hardcoded but instead it is all encapsulated in the 
        # AwesomeOperation class.
        for awesome_operation in self.awesome_operations:
            awesome_variable = awesome_operation.execute(value=awesome_variable)

        return awesome_variable


# Here you can see how the parent class and the child class would be created. You could also create two classes and 
# initialize the awesome_operations in the init directly.
parent = AwesomeClass(
    awesome_attribute=10.0,
    awesome_operations=[
        AwesomeOperation(operation_type=AwesomeOperation.OPERATION_TYPE_SUM, operation_value=1),
        AwesomeOperation(operation_type=AwesomeOperation.OPERATION_TYPE_MULT, operation_value=2)
    ])

child = AwesomeClass(
    awesome_attribute=10.0,
    awesome_operations=[
        AwesomeOperation(operation_type=AwesomeOperation.OPERATION_TYPE_SUM, operation_value=1),
        AwesomeOperation(operation_type=AwesomeOperation.OPERATION_TYPE_SUM, operation_value=-5),
        AwesomeOperation(operation_type=AwesomeOperation.OPERATION_TYPE_MULT, operation_value=2)
    ])
```